# Cannot read property 'rotation' of undefined : Three.js error

Tags: rotation, three.js

I have a problem reported by the console of Google Chrome. I am on Ubuntu 12.04. The problem in the console is :

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rotation' of undefined
```

(reported five times).

And I can modify the position without problem in the function init() with these lines :

```
object.position.y = 0;
```

Also, I declare my variable object as a global variable.

I create a scene by importing an object (obj +mtl) with THREE.OBJMTLLoader(). And then for animate my object I do :

```
    object.rotation.y += 0.01;
```

The problem comes from the previous declaration. It's weird because it's working but I have this problem in the console. Do you know what could I do to fix it?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 5):

Loading is asynchronous. You are likely calling `animate()` before the object is fully loaded.

Put the `animate()` call in the loader callback.

Or alternatively, add the object to the scene in the loader callback.

See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_obj_mtl.html.